# Random number generator repeats every time?

Tags: c++, random, windows-7

I'm trying to find a random number generator that will give me a single random number each time I run it. I have spent a week trying dozens of different ones, both from this site and others. Every time I run it, it gives me the same number! The only time it changes is if I change the range, and then it just gives me the new number over and over.
I am running Code::Blocks ver. 16.01 on Windows 7. Can anyone help?? I'm at my wits' end!

This code gives me a decently ramdom string of numbers, but still the same string each time!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 eng(rd()); std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(0, 10);

  for(int n=0; n<100; ++n)
    std::cout << distr(eng) << '\t';
}
```

I have tried the code on my compiler app on my phone as well.

Comment: Maybe show us some code?

Comment: The standard library random number generators work very well. The problem is in your code, which you haven't shown.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374382/c-mpi-easiest-way-to-create-random-data/36374680#36374680

Comment: I think he doesn't use a seed and a default one may be a hard-coded value. Without supplied code I can't be sure.

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 eng(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(0, 10);

for(int n=0; n<100; ++n)
std::cout << distr(eng) << '\t';


this one gives a fairly good spread, but I want one number at a time, and even this one, always gives me the same string.
I COULD give you guys every different code I've used, but I would be typing for a LONG time.

Comment: That is the correct way of doing this. The most important part is the seeding of the mt19937 instance from your rd device (which you seem to be doing). And it belongs in your question as a code-list. Btw, when I use that exact code, my sequence arbitrarily differs with each run of the program.

Comment: I don't know, either. When I have it give me one number at a time instead of a string of numbers, it always gives me 6, even after closing the program and reopening it. Even shutting my computer down completely, out still gives me the same number. Is an rd device hardware or software?

Comment: @AzaraThunderbird The standard allows std::random_device to be implemented in terms of a pseudo-random number generator if  there is no real random source on the system. You may need to find a different entropy source, such as the time, or user touch co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard allows `std::random_device` to be implemented in terms of a pseudo-random number generator if there is no real random source on the system.

You may need to find a different entropy source, such as the time, or user touch co-ordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Every pseudo random number generator will return the same sequence of numbers for the same initial seed value.
What you want to do is to use a different seed every time you run the program. Otherwise you'll just be using the same default seed every time and get the same values.

Picking good seeds is not as easy as you might think. Using the output from `time(nullptr)` for example still gives the same results if two copies of the program run within the same second. Using the value of `getpid()` is also bad since pid values wrap and thus sometimes you'll get the same value for different runs.  Luckily you have other options. `std::seed_seq` lets you combine multiple bad sources and returns a good (or rather, pretty good) seed value you can use. There is also `std::random_device` which (on all sane implementations) returns raw entropy - perfect for seeding a pseudo random generator (or you can just use it directly if it is fast enough for your purpose) or you can combine it with `std::seed_seq` and the bad sources to seed a generator if you are worried it might be implemented as a prng on your implementation.

I would advice you to read this page:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random for an overview of how to deal with random number generation in modern C++.